# How do I apply a style?

Tags: microsoft-excel, styles

I have to conditionally apply a style to a cell in Excel. I know how to do it in LibreOffice calc:

```
=B4+STYLE(IF(ABS(B4-B3)/B4>0.07,"Red","Default"))
```

How do I do it in Excel?

Excell recognizes `ABS` and `IF` -- but not `STYLE`. What is the analogue for `STYLE` in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that within the formula in Excel, I assume the **worksheet** formula will be just

`=B4`

then you can use **"conditional formatting"** from Home tab. Use the option "use a formula to determine which cells to format" then apply a similar formula to the above, i.e.

`=ABS(B4-B3)/B4>0.07`

select red fill or font > OK

You can apply to a range of cells if you wish, just use the formula that applies to the top left cell of range.

My instructions assume you are using Excel 2007 or later....